# can you catch a discard or dropped packet?

Tags: packet-tracer

we all know "Time-to-Live: 8-bit binary value that indicates the remaining "life" of the packet. 
if becomes zero, the router discards or drops the packet and it is removed from the network data flow.

my question here is , can the sender  ( OR anyone else beside the sender  ) catch these dropped packets somehow

and IF these packets where to be accessed after being dropped (assuming we can catch them)  is it possible to get data from them (even if not complete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last hop to receive the packet before it hits the TTL limit would see the packet in its normal form. Once this hop (router/switch/firewall/etc) realises that the TTL has been reached, it will drop the packet.

Therefore to view this packet before it is dropped you would need to capture the inbound traffic on the last hop, or SPAN (port mirror) it in order to view what it looked like before it was dropped.

If the last hop happens to be a Cisco router you could use the [Embedded Packet Capture](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/epc/command/epc-cr-book/epc-cr-m1.html) to capture the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Once the packet is dropped, it's gone forever. The SPAN idea mentioned above is great for viewing a mirrored version of the packet at the last hop, but technically it isn't dropped. To my knowledge, there isn't a program that stores dropped packets for later viewing.